# Collection view reusing images while scrolling in swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm simply desperate, searched for 6 hours now and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a collection view with images loaded from a remote server and while scrolling the cells are being refreshed with previous images for a few seconds before settling.
Tried overriding "prepare for reuse" and setting the imageview image to nil but it is still not working..
Would appreciate an example from someone who got it working,

thanks a lot!

**EDIT - ADDING THE CODE**

CollectionView:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! PictureCell

    cell.pictureCD = GalleryCD().fetchTable()[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

CollectionViewCell:

```
class PictureCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!

var pictureCD: NSManagedObject! {
    didSet { self.setupData() }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.picture.image = nil
    self.picture.setNeedsDisplay() // tried adding after some recommendations
    self.setNeedsDisplay()         // tried adding after some recommendations
}

func setupData(){
    self.picture.image = UIImage(named: "blank")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        let URL = (NSURL (string: url.pictureSquareGET(picture: self.pictureCD)))!

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL)!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.picture.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Did you call super.prepareForReuse as first statement in prepareForReuse?

Comment: pasted the code above, thanks

Comment: @John are you able to find solution. Please suggest me the fix if you found solution for this i am also facing same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can update the prepareForReuse method

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    myImageView.image = nil

    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cells have previous images loaded into them because of cell reuse so you are correct there.

All you should need to do is set the cells image as nil in your cellForItemAtIndexPath BEFORE fetching the updated ones from your server.

Comment: That's the obvious solution Beau but prepareForReuse should set the image already to nil.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look and see if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you still experience the same problem?

Comment: @Dima Could you upload your solution if you got it working? I'm struggling with similar problem